# spring data jpa Pageable Sort Error

Tags: spring

He preguntado en stackoverflow la siguiente pregunta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439392/spring-data-jpa-pageable-sort-exception

spring boot (1.3.5), spring-data, spring-data-jpa, JPA(hibernate/hsqldb).

POM:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

<groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
<artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
```

El código de configuración:

```
@Bean
public PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(
        SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver sortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver) {

    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver phmar = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(
            sortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver);
    phmar.setOneIndexedParameters(false);
    phmar.setPageParameterName("page");
    phmar.setSizeParameterName("size");
    phmar.setMaxPageSize(20);
    return phmar;
}

@Bean
public SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver sortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {

    SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver shmar = new SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    shmar.setSortParameter("sort");
    return shmar;
}
```

El controlador:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/List", "" })
public String list(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) String searchString,
        @SortDefault(sort = "code", direction = Direction.ASC) @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 20) Pageable pageable) {
```

// Lo he intentado también con  @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 20, sort = "code", direction = Direction.ASC) pero no funciona.

```
    Page<T> page;
    if (!isEmpty(searchString))
        page = service.search(searchString, pageable);  // <-- ERROR
    else
        page = service.findAll(pageable);  // <-- OK
```

El servicio (simplificado):

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<T> search(String str, Pageable pageable) {
    return repository.search(str, pageable);
}
```

El repositorio (simplificado):

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<T, Integer> {
(...)
@Query(value = "SELECT a FROM #{#entityName} a WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%'))")
Page<T> search(@Param("str") String str, Pageable pageable);
```

}

Lo he intentado con la misma `@Query` pero con `return List<>` en vez de `Page<>` y sin el parámetro `Pageable pageable`, y funciona.

```
// con esta @Query de prueba:
@Query(value = "SELECT a FROM #{#entityName} a WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%'))")
List<T> search(@Param("str") String str);
```

Cuando llamo a `findAll(pageable)` funciona pero cuando llamo a `search(str, pageable) (str="AT")` no funciona.

Salida del navegador:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed May 25 15:16:24 CEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 151 **[SELECT a FROM prueba.entity.AccountType a WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%')) order by a.code: ASC asc**]; ** nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 151 **[SELECT a FROM prueba.entity.AccountType a WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%')) order by a.code: ASC asc]**
```

**El SQL es invalido!  Extra ":" y duplicado "ASC asc".**

Salida de console:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(accounttyp0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        account_type accounttyp0_ 
    where
        accounttyp0_.code like ('%'||?||'%') 
        or upper(accounttyp0_.name) like upper(('%'||?||'%'))
mo.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter       line 1:151: **unexpected token:     :**
mo.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter       line 1:151: **unexpected token:     :**

antlr.NoViableAltException: **unexpected token: :**
    at         org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3694)     [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]

(more and more)

near line 1, column 151 **[SELECT a FROM prueba.entity.AccountType a     WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE     UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%')) order by a.code: ASC asc];** nested exception     is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:     org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: :     near line 1, column 151 **[SELECT a FROM prueba.entity.AccountType a WHERE     a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE     UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%')) order by a.code: ASC asc]] with root cause**

**org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:     : near line 1, column 151 **[SELECT a FROM     prueba.entity.AccountType a WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR     UPPER(a.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%')) order by a.code: ASC asc]**
    at     org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxExcept    ion.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @MiguelAngel. Por favor provee la información relevante para reproducir tu problema.

Comment: @Luiggi-Mendoza He actualizado la pregunta con todo la información.

Comment: @jasilva He actualizado la información.

Comment: ¿Has intentado quitar el campo `value` de tu `@Query`, es decir `@Query("SELECT a FROM #{#entityName} a WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%'))")`? Porque al parecer el problema es que no reconoce los dos puntos `:` en el query.

Comment: El query genera `SELECT .... order by a.code: ASC asc` como si le indicaras que haga el order en dos momentos. En teoria esto deberai funcionar bien `@SortDefault(sort = "code", direction = Direction.ASC)` no se si puedas limpiar el proyecto quitando la linea anterior y ejecutandolo asi

Comment: @Luiggi-mendoza segun esto http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html `value` no deberia ser el problema, pero probaré.

Comment: @jasilva El error es el que indicas, pero la causa no la se. He probado esto: `@SortDefault(sort = "code", direction = Direction.ASC) @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 20) Pageable pageable` y `@PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 20, sort = "code", direction = Direction.ASC)` y ambos fallan con @Query pero ambos funcionan en findAll(pageable).

Comment: Ok, una pregunta ¿comó construyes `pageable`?  en `if (!isEmpty(searchString))
        page = service.search(searchString, pageable);  <-- ERROR`

Comment: @Luiggi-mendoza He quitar `value`y falla igual.

Comment: @jasilva pageable la construye spring. la crea automaticamente en el metodo list del controller (como el resto de parametros de list(...). pageable es correcto porque findAll la usa sin problemas. Lo que falla es la combinación @Query+pageable.

Comment: Ok, entonces no estas modificando nada despues de la creación de spring, podrias debuggearlo para ver que trae, puede ser que tenga algo mal en el qualifierDelimiter

Comment: He intentado debugarlo pero como es un tema interno de spring no veo nada (a veces odio la magia de spring). Debe ser alguna restricción o algo de @query (en la doc dice que la paginación/ordenación no esta permitida si es nativa, pero ya he probado tambien a ponerlo a nativeQuery = false y tampoco. Algún guru en la sala!?

Comment: Debugando pageable:                                                                                 Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: code: DESC]

Comment: una pregunta mas ¿que versiones tienes de tus librerias?

Comment: spring boot 1.3.5 es la única versión de mi POM.

Comment: @Luiggi-mendoza  Alguna idea?